# python virtualenv is not creating

Tags: python-2.7

i want to create python virtualenv with python version 2.7.6 but there is error as follow , even i wanted to reinstall pip but it showed that pip is of latest version:

$ virtualenv cow-env

```
  New python executable in cow-env/bin/python Installing setuptools,   
  pip...
  Complete output from command /home/cow/cow/cow-env/bin    /python     -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.5debian1-py2.py3-  
  none-any.whl   /pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

  File "/usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.5debian1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
  /pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
   File "/usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.5debian1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  /pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.5debian1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
  /pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>

  ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
   ----------------------------------------
  ...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 3, in <module>
   virtualenv.main()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
   symlink=options.symlink)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 993, in   
  create_environment
   install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 961, in   
   install_wheel
   'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 903,  
   in call_subprocess
   % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
  OSError: Command /home/cow/cow/cow-env/bin/python -c "import   sys,pip;   sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

output of $pip --version is as follow:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
   from pip import main
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 60, in      <module>
   from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 19, in          <module>
   from distlib import version
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl       /distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl         /distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
   ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been resolved by reinstalling the libpython2.7-stdlib package.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libpython2.7-stdlib
```

this re installation placed the missing file _ssl.so in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload.